# Calculate CRC32, MD5 and SHA1 of zip content without decompression in Python

Tags: python, hash, md5, sha1, crc32

I need to calculate the CRC32, MD5 and SHA1 of the content of zip files without decompressing them.

So far I found out how to calculate these for the zip files itself, e.g.:

**CRC32:**

```
import zlib


zip_name = "test.zip"


def Crc32Hasher(file_path):

    buf_size = 65536
    crc32 = 0

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(buf_size)
            if not data:
                break
            crc32 = zlib.crc32(data, crc32)

    return format(crc32 & 0xFFFFFFFF, '08x')


print(Crc32Hasher(zip_name))
```

**SHA1:** (MD5 similarly)

```
import hashlib


zip_name = "test.zip"


def Sha1Hasher(file_path):

    buf_size = 65536
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(buf_size)
            if not data:
                break
            sha1.update(data)

    return format(sha1.hexdigest())


print(Sha1Hasher(zip_name))
```

For the content of the zip file, I can read the CRC32 from the zip directly without the need of calculating it as follow:

**Read CRC32 of zip content:**

```
import zipfile

zip_name = "test.zip"

if zip_name.lower().endswith(('.zip')):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "r")

for info in z.infolist():

    print(info.filename,
          format(info.CRC & 0xFFFFFFFF, '08x'))
```

But I couldn't figure out how to calculate the SHA1 (or MD5) of the content of zip files without decompressing them first.
Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible. You can get CRC because it was carefully precalculated for you when archive is created (it is used for integrity check). Any other checksum/hash has to be calculated from scratch and will require at least streaming of the archive content, i.e. unpacking.

**UPD**: Possibble implementations

`libarchive`: extra dependencies, supports many archive formats

```
import libarchive.public as libarchive
with libarchive.file_reader(fname) as archive:
    for entry in archive:
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        for block in entry.get_blocks():
            md5.update(block)
        print(str(entry), md5.hexdigest())
```

Native `zipfile`: no dependencies, zip only

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(fname)
blocksize = 1024**2  #1M chunks
for fname in archive.namelist():
    entry = archive.open(fname)
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        block = entry.read(blocksize)
        if not block:
            break
        md5.update(block)
    print(fname, md5.hexdigest())
```

Comment: thanks for answering. What would be the most memory efficient way of doing that?